# I Want to display items in listview from database as values of checkbox. in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, checkbox

I Am new to android programming...

I want to make a app where i can bind checkbox to database...

i mean based on state of checkbox ( or the no. of checkbox checked ) the values should be retrieved from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in SQLite there is no boolean values, but they are represented as 1 for true and 0 for false.
if you try searching for those values you can figure out if the condition is true or false;

```
int booleanRow = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(FIELD);
boolean isChecked = (cursor.getInt(booleanRow) == 1)? true : false;
```